# Scroll bottom of browser viewport to top of element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to setup a click event that will scroll the bottom of the viewport to top of element, this will basically make the element not visible to the user.

So for example I have an element on the page with the id of `footer` so then I would like to do the following:

```
if ($('#footer').visible(true)) {
    // #footer is visible, scroll the bottom of the browser viewport to the top of the #footer element.
}
```

Any idea how this can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `animate()` to scroll to element. `scrollTop` property force browser to scrolling to `Y` position.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
   if ($("#footer").is(":visible")) {
      var topPos = $("#footer").offset().top;
      var winHeight = $(window).height();

      $("html, body").animate({
           scrollTop: topPos - winHeight
      }, 1000);
   }
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 1000px;  
}

.space {
    height: 500px;
}

#footer {
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Go</button>
<div class="space"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$("#yourButtton").click(function() {
   if($("#footer").is(":visible")) {
      $("html, body").animate({
           scrollTop: $("#footer").offset().top
      }, 500);
   }
});
```

I hope this is what you are expecting. 
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks this does do something however it scrolls to the bottom of the element #footer and not the top

Comment: In that case you can do this: scrollTop: $("#footer").offset().top - $("#footer").height()